# Hadoop Cluster Configuration for Processing 400 GB + 10 GB Incremental

Tags: hadoop

I have 400 GB old data and I will get 10 GB incremental data daily. To process the whole Data(400 GB + 10 GB(incre)) how many nodes(Namenode and Datanode), Server Capacity and RAM required to configure Hadoop Cluster with default RF 3?

Comment: Hi, please provide a [mcve] so that we could help you better!

Comment: I want to know what is the suitable cluster configuration for the given requirement.

Comment: Mainly 1. Storage of server 2. Data nodes count 3. RAM